# doParallel with own created functions

Tags: r

I have created a sequential simulation in R to iterate a process 10,0000 times. This takes ~70 minutes and so I decided to try the same thing in parallel with the doParallel package.

My foreach loop calls on a function called 'inv.predict' that is not in any existing package. When I run the code I get an error.

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
ptm <- proc.time()
clupeaformis_cr <- foreach(i = 1:100, .packages = c("spider", "investr", "mgcv")) %dopar% {
clupeaformis_cr <- rep(NA,  i)
clupeaformis_haplo_rand <- haploAccum(clupeaformis_aligned, method = "random", permutations = 1000) 

N <- clupeaformis_haplo_rand$sequences
H <- clupeaformis_haplo_rand$n.haplotypes
d <- data.frame(N, H)

clupeaformis_cr <- gam(H ~ s(N, bs = "cr", k = 20), optimizer = c("outer", "bfgs"), data = d)
clupeaformis_cr[i] <- inv.predict(clupeaformis_cr, y = 21, x.name = "N", interval = TRUE, 
               lower = 1, upper = 1000000)      
}

proc.time() - ptm
stopCluster(cl)


Error in { : 
   task 1 failed - "no applicable method for 'inv.predict' applied to an object of class "c('gam', 'glm', 'lm')""
```

I am unsure as to why this doesn't work in parallel but it does in a regular for loop. This question is related to another one that I posted yesterday.

Any assistance is warmly welcomed.

Comment: please properly format your code so it appears as code using 4 space indentetion.

Comment: You need to write the whole function for `inv.predict` within the curly brackets of `%dopar% {...` as well. You can also *export* `inv.predict` with the statement `clusterEvalQ( cl, { <function for inv.predict> } )`.

Comment: Great! Just what I need!

Comment: @ChiPak It seems that putting the function within %dopar% { ...} is cumbersome as the function is very long. Exporting via clusterEvalQ() seems to have this effect too... Is there a better way?

Comment: Perhaps there's a way but I don't know of it. The issue is that each worker is an independent environment, and it only looks in its local environment for data/custom functions. Perhaps you can try `clusterEvalQ( cl, { <function_name> } ) or some derivative, but I'm not sure it'll work.

Comment: See argument `.export` of `foreach()`

Comment: CPak should add this as an answer since I think this is what the person needed, and by the way, I needed it too

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this.

A general solution is as follows:

```
cl <- makeCluster(4) # set number of cluster/cores for parallelization 
registerDoParallel(cl) # register clusters

ptm <- proc.time() # start timer

my_function <- foreach(i = 1:1000, .packages = c(...)) %dopar% { # foreach loop

my_vec <- rep(NA,  i) # preallocate results to a empty vector

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # set number of cluster/cores for parallelization 
registerDoParallel(cl) # register clusters

my_vec[i] <- YOUR CODE HERE # filled vector with results

}

proc.time() - ptm # stop timer

stopCluster(cl)
```

Keep in mind that running in parallel may actually slow down your workflow if there are too many workers (clusters/cores) communicating at once.